# Installing PyMySQL on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, pymysql

I am not a python user and though I have used MySQL, I'm not an expert.  Also, I'm mainly a Windows user and I don't know much about running command line scripts.  So this might be a stupid question but I want to ask anyway...

(BTW my purpose is to install 'Baseball On A Stick')

I installed Python (version 3.3 on a Windows 7 machine).

Next it says to install pymysql.  So I downloaded the .zip file from https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/

The Readme says "Simply run the build-py3k.sh script from the local directory. It will build a working package in the ./py3k directory."  I have absolutely no idea what this means.  How do I run this?  I tried typing it into the Python command line interface and it just gave me an error.

Comment: I found the Baseball On a Stick forums on Sourceforge and I have received some help with this via that route.  For future reference, BBOS requires Python 2.7, and there are now new installation instructions so pymysql is no longer required.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/AY2012/cs2316_fall/presentations/HOWTO_install_pymysql_windows.pdf
has some pretty clear instructions, and worked for me on windows 8 running python 3.3
zip here:
http://www.summet.com/dmsi/html/codesamples/pymysql3.zip

Comment: This helped me. Be sure to run your `cmd.exe` as administrator if you use Windows 7, otherwise you may not have permissions to install.

Answer (score 0):

win+r and then input cmd
then in the dos input the command：pip install pyMySQL
but if your computer has not install pip, please reference this page https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

**Python connect xampp mysql windows with pymysql:**

Step-1:

Run Command Prompt
    D:\python-3.6.2\Scripts> **pip install pymysql**

Step-2:

```
#!D:/python-3.6.2/python.exe 
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n")
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='python_mysql')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM authors")
print(cur.description)
print(" Test")
for row in cur:
    print(row)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Save the file as testconn.py in htdocs/PythonProject & open http://localhost/PythonProject\test.py